# Extract resource folder from running jar in Java 7

Tags: java, jar, resources, java-7, nio

My resources folder inside my jar includes a directory with several binary files. I am attempting to use this code to extract them:

```
try(InputStream is = ExternalHTMLThumbnail.class.getResourceAsStream("/wkhtmltoimage")) {
    Files.copy(is, Paths.get("/home/dan/wkhtmltoimage");
}
```

This is throwing the error

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/dan/wkhtmltoimage

Which comes from

```
if (errno() == UnixConstants.ENOENT)
    return new NoSuchFileException(file, other, null);
```

in UnixException.java. Even though in Files.java the correct options are passed:

```
ostream = newOutputStream(target, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW,
    StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
```

from `Files.copy`. Of course there's not! That's why I'm trying to make it. I don't yet understand `Path` and `Files` enough to do this right. What's the best way to extract the directory and all its contents?

Confused because the docs for `Files.copy` claims

> By default, the copy fails if the target file already exists or is a symbolic link

(Apparently it fails if the target file doesn't exist as well?)

And lists the possible exceptions, and `NoSuchFileException` is not one of them.

Comment: I think the error is my input stream is faulty. Stand by.

Comment: No, the NoSuchFileException refers the target `Path`, not the input `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
URL url = Resources.getResource(ExternalHTMLThumbnail.class, "wkhtmltoimage");
byte[] bytes = Resources.toByteArray(url);
Files.write(bytes, new File("/my/path/myFile"));
```

You could of course just chain that all into one line; I declared the variables to make it more readable.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary to load the whole resource into RAM though.

Comment: This doesn't compile. Files.write(byte[]. File) does not exist, and that's the operation that is throwing in my version.

Comment: Files is Guava's; not the JDK's: com.google.common.io.Files. If your resource is in a .jar, I'd guess it's sized such that the ephemeral use of a bit of RAM is probably no big deal? Anyways; the above is just a quick suggestion; it's your problem to solve, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

The *file* that does not exist may actually be the *directory* you're trying to create the file in.

> /home/dan/wkhtmltoimage

Does `/home/dan` exist? Probably not if you're on a Mac.